# iOS - UIView below UITableView for settings

Tags: ios, ios5

What I try to implement in my App is to put a View, probably another tableView below the main tableview to enter some filter settings.

In the optimal case the main tableview should slide half way down and be greyed out like in the example from Appshopper that I put. How could I implement such a behaviour?

I'm using IOS5/6 and the storyboard

[image: AppShopper]

Comment: Do you want to display image on tableViewCell ?

Comment: No, I want to have filter options in a hidden layer under the tableview. When the user wants to set them, the tabeview should slide down and uncover the settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I figured out how to do it.

Just put both views into your Controller, and on Event triggered execute something like the following code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

CGRect newFrame = self.newsTableView.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = newFrame.origin.y + self.subview.frame.size.height;
[self.subView1 setFrame:newFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Of course what's still missing is the check if the frame hasn't already been moved down and so on, but the m

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make a view which contains two subviews: The settings view and the main table view. Using Core Animation you can animate the main table view moving downwards.
Using storyboard, you push the encapsulating view onto you viewcontroller.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. So I need to have two animations? One that slides in the settings and one that slides out the tableview